# Cascading DropDown with "disabled" problems

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to disable a select with the Knockout property `disabled`. When I update the first select which has a property I made (`dep`), it must remove the disable of the IDelement on dep.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.singleChosen = {

    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).chosen();

        **//Disabled if element have disableOptions default=disabled**
        if(allBindingsAccessor()["disableOptions"]){
            if(allBindingsAccessor()["disableOptions"].default == "disabled"){
                $(element).attr('disabled', true);
            }
        }

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        //Remove disabled of the elementID on disableOptions dep:
        if(allBindingsAccessor()["disableOptions"]){
            if(allBindingsAccessor()["disableOptions"].dep !== ""){
                var dep = allBindingsAccessor()["disableOptions"].dep;
               $(document.getElementById(dep)).attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }

        ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
        $(element).trigger("liszt:updated");
    }

};
```

Corresponding HTML:

```html
<td>
   <select id="region" 
           data-bind="
           singleChosen: newData,
           optionsText: 'Name',
           value: region,
           disableOptions: {
               default:'',
               msg:'',
               dep: 'pais'
           }">
    </select>
</td>
<td data-bind="with: region">
    <select id='pais' 
            data-bind="
                singleChosen: Countries, 
                optionsText: 'Name',
                optionsCaption: 'Selecciona un pais',  
                value: $parent.country,
                disableOptions: {
                    default:'disabled',
                    msg:'',
                    dep: ''
                }">
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't see why someone would downvote this?? I am resetting the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
  $(document.getElementById(dep)).attr('disabled', false);
```

with

```
  $(document.getElementById(dep)).removeAttr('disabled');
```

disabled attribute does not require a value. by default, when you specify disabled, the item will be disabled.